# Filesystem for sharing GIT-projects between Windows and Linux

Tags: filesystems

My desktop PC holds 3 hard disks. 1 with Linux Mint installed, 1 with Windows 10 installed and another disk for sharing files between Windows and Linux.

The biggest part of these files are my programming projects which are versioned with git. I want these files to be readable and usable from both Windows and Linux. However I have no idea which file system for this is best to use.

These file systems I have already tried:

- NTFS -> Gives permission changes on all files in git-repositories
- FAT32 + ExFAT -> Can't use symlinks which is barely useable (Especially with Symfony Projects)
- EXT4 -> Using Ext2Fsd on Windows / Repositories not readable in my git-gui on Windows (GitKraken).

What do you think is the best option?

Comment: You shouldn't share working trees anyway, because the line endings won't match. If you check out separate working copies on each platform from bare repositories on a shared drive then permissions & symlinks won't matter.

Comment: Just check out two clones of the repository; one on Windows and one on Linux. Commit and push your work to a server before switching OSes.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of had the same problem before. Is on-line Git repository an option? If so, some services like [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) let you have **private** repositories for **free**, if number of developers is limited.

Comment: I'm already doing this. I use a gogs service on my server. I just need to know which filesystem is best to share files between windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a local server on an old PC.

If you don't have an old PC, something like a headless Raspberry Pi would cost almost nothing to set-up and running cost (power) would be very small.

There are so many advantages to this than trying to share everything on a single dual boot system I don't know where to begin.

You could use Git tools directly.

You could access the files over Samba or an NFS.

The server does not care what OS you run.

The tools on each OS don't care what the server is running.

Your small server could be on 24/7, so it could do cron jobs in the background while you sleep :]